# Reload page from ajax-loaded subpage

Tags: php, ajax, redirect

I am using ajax to load php generated content into main div on some menu click.

What I would like to do is have some kind of reload functionality - if some timeout expires I want user to reauthenticate, I am checking this on menu click before the content is loaded into div.

If I do this with php's
 header("location:login");

I guess it wants to redirect inside loading div, but I want the whole page to redirect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do is some thing like this

At the top of your file

```
ob_start();
```

Add this to the end of your php file

```
if($_SEESION['active']){
    ob_end_flush()
}else{
    ob_clean();
    echo "{Session_invalid}";
    ob_end_flush();
}
```

Then in your AJAX(XMLHttpRequest)

```
ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("GET", "/folder/yourFile.php", true);
ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(readyState == 4){
        if(ajax.responseText == "{Session_invalid}"){
            document.location = "http://your.authenticate.url/"
        }else{
            mydiv.innerHTML = ajax.responceText
        }
    }
}
ajax.send();
```

Please note i have built this on what you have said dont remove your ajax just add the if check into the AJAX

Allso this code has been built so you can add it into any file, even if you did not make the php file so its just top and bottom edits please make sure there in the  tags though

This matches 
user228395 point 1

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, redirecting a XmlHttpRequest doesn't make much sense. You have basically a few options.

1. You let your AJAX call return something that makes your javascript understand that you need to a direct (in that case, redirect with javascript).
2. You do an AJAX call before you are trying to load the content in the div to check if the user needs to authenticate.
3. You keep a variable/cookie to check if the user's session has expired. Before every request you check if that is the case. If so, you let the user authenticate.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi,thanks to both, will try it, not sure which solution yet. I forgot to say that I am using jquery for ajax, I guess I can get it with success form jquery post and match it to "{Session_invalid}" response....