# session & iframe

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a site with an iframe.
Booth, the site and the site in the iframe are checking `$_SESSION["login"]`.
So if the Session gets expiered the user will be logged out.

Problem:
When the user hangs around the site for some time and the session gets expiered the login-page will appear in the iframe.
(for example he clicks a link with target="iframe")
I want the login-page to appear in the parent.

Possible?

Comment: Have you considered using something other than an IFRAME to display your sub-content?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102878/better-alternative-to-an-iframe - Not sure, but I think loading your page into a DIV via AJAX will make it so some forms of redirect will redirect the whole page instead of just the sub-page, as the browser will (sort of) treat it all as one page.  See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213122/reload-page-from-ajax-loaded-subpage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
<?php 
   if(!isset($_SESSION["login"]))
   {
?>
<script>
   if(self.location.href != top.location.href){
       top.location = '/login.php';
   }
</script>
<?php
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can use Javascript, use `top` to access the top parent page, and for instance redirect it to the login page.

Answer (score 1):

If session expire time is not mandatory, why not set the session to not expire until the browser is closed?

```
<?php ini_set("session.gc_lifetime","0"); ?>
```

this setting sets that the session will not expire until the browser is closed.
If you have access to php.ini you can set that to default

Answer (score 1):

Add a check to your login page wheter or not it is loaded inside the iframe, like so:

```
var isInIFrame = (window.location != window.parent.location) ? true : false;
```

If it evaluates to true, try reloading the page in the top window, like so:

```
window.top.location.href="/login.php"
```